# INestSerializer removed on NEST2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, elasticsearch, nest

Looks like NEST2 INestSerializer has been removed but I can't find the substitute for it in the current source code.

The [breaking changes page](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/nest-breaking-changes.md) lists it under the removed classes

What's the new class to use?

Comment: Looks like [there is no counterpart](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/1510), `IElasticsearchSerializer` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in Nest 2.x is [`IElasticsearchSerializer`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Serialization/IElasticsearchSerializer.cs) with the default implementation being [`JsonNetSerializer`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/CommonAbstractions/SerializationBehavior/JsonNetSerializer.cs), a json serializer that uses Json.Net under the covers.

In cases where you want to add Contract Converters (for custom type serialization/deserialization) or to define custom property mapping (outside of using attributes, automapping, fluent mapping or mapping visitor), then you'll probably want to derive from `JsonNetSerializer`.

Comment: thank you very much @Russ. I accepted the answer albeit it didn't solve completely the issue. Feel free to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695364/nest2-initialization-on-net-c-sharp-webapi