# NEST2 initialization on .NET C# WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, elasticsearch, nest

I defined the NEST2 client dependencies like this:

```
  container.RegisterType<IElasticClient, ElasticClient>(
        new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter<IConnectionSettingsValues>(),
            new OptionalParameter<IConnection>(),
            new OptionalParameter<IElasticsearchSerializer>(),
            new OptionalParameter<ITransport>()));
```

I was using NEST and ElasticSearch. Now I moved to NEST 2 and ElasticSearch 2 and I had to change `INestSerializer` into `IElasticsearchSerializer`

Unfortunately now I've got this error on `ITransport`

> Using the generic type ITransport requires 1 type
>   arguments

What should I pass to ITransport? I tried changing the line to:

```
 new OptionalParameter<ITransport<IConnectionConfigurationValues>>()));
```

but I get this exception at runtime:

> The type Nest.ElasticClient does not have a constructor that takes the
>   parameters (IConnectionSettingsValues, IConnection,
>   IElasticsearchSerializer, ITransport`1)

What should I do now?

**EDIT**

The current constructors for the `ElasticClient` class are:

- `()`
- `(IConnectionSettingValues connSettings)`
- `(ITransport<IConnectionSettingValues tran)`
- `(Uri uri)`

So basically I can pass nothing, a connection setting, a transport or the URL endpoint

My Elasticsearch 2 is using username and a password so I bet I should use either the second or the third constructor overload

Comment: What is the actual constructor signature of ElasticClient?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion please have a look at my question edit

Comment: My guess is that you have to pick just one constructor that you want to use and create an InjectionConstructor with just the one required parameter. That is, unless I'm misunderstanding what InjectionConstructor is representing.